# Constant Animation on Pygame Sprites

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, sprite

I have recently been trying to make a animation where my sprite moves back and forth between 2 picture in a constantly without any pause. I was wondering how to go about doing this. Any help would be appreciated, so far what I have:

```
import pygame
import os
import time
import sys

image1 = pygame.image.load("image1.png")
image2 = pygame.image.load("image2.png")

class sprite(object): 
    def __init__(self):
        super(sprite, self).__init__()
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

    def handle_keys(self):

        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        distance = 1 
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]: 
            self.y += distance

        if key[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.y -= distance

        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]: 
            self.x += distance
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]: 
            self.x -= distance


    def draw(self, surface):

        surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1600, 800))

sprite=sprite() 
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True
while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            running = False

    sprite.handle_keys() 

    screen.fill((255,255,255)) 
    sprite.draw(screen) 
    pygame.display.update() 

    clock.tick(40)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [`pyganim`](http://inventwithpython.com/pyganim/) module for `pygame`. In your script, import `pyganim`, create `PygAnimation` from 2 png files, and blit it onto surface:

```
import pyganim
anim = pyganim.PygAnimation([("image1.png", 0.1), ("image2.png", 0.1)])
anim.play()
... 
def draw(self, surface):
    anim.blit(surface, (self.x, self.y))
```

Comment: Thanks this proved to be the simplest way, also thanks for introducing me to this new tool. Will make my life much easier.

Answer (score 0):

In my game resources, I made a class `Animate()` that stores the time, current index, and the list of images. I haven't updated in a while, but this is how its `anim()` method currently works.

```
def anim(self, dest, pos, rate, loop=True):
    self.time += 1
    if self.time%rate == 0:
        self.index += 1

    if self.index > len(self.imgs)-1:
        if loop:
            self.index = 0
        else:
            self.index = len(self.imgs)-1

    dest.blit(self.imgs[self.index], pos)
```

Here's how I use it.

```
img1 = pygame.image.load('img1.png')
img2 = pygame.image.load('img2.png')
animate = Animate([img1, img2])

while True:
    animate.anim(screen, sprite.pos, 10)
    ....
```

BTW `rate` is not based on seconds so it may vary from machine to machine which is why I fix my framerate so it doesn't go too fast.

Comment: I am having trouble making an Animate class to allow this line to work:                     animate = Animate([img1, img2])                                                                            Could you provide an example?